# How to use FunSpec.overriding? in KotlinPoet

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

Submitted by [Fleshgrinder](https://github.com/Fleshgrinder) on [GitHub](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet).

The `FunSpec` class has the very handy overriding method, however, it is unclear how this can be used while generating code.

Minimal example:

```
FileSpec.builder("com.fleshgrinder", "KotlinPoet").apply {
    val className = ClassName("com.fleshgrinder", "KotlinPoet")
    addType(TypeSpec.classBuilder(className).apply {
        addFunction(FunSpec.builder("toString").apply {
            addModifiers(KModifier.OVERRIDE)
            addStatement("""return "KotlinPoet"""")
        }.build())
    }.build())
}.build().writeTo(System.out)
```

Which generates:

```
class KotlinPoet {
    override fun toString() = "KotlinPoet"
}
```

The output it generates is perfect but the code to generate it is not.

```
FunSpec.overriding(Any::toString).apply {
    addStatement("""return "KotlinPoet"""")
}.build()
```

Comment: What is exactly your question? How to override a method?