# KotlinPoet how to use FunSpec.overriding when the class is not present?

Tags: kotlin, annotation-processing, kotlinpoet

I have a package name and a class name as `String`s but I don't have the class specifically in my annotation processor. I need to use:

```
FunSpec.overriding(getOnlyElement(methodsIn(//stuck here)))
```

The `stuck here` should be a `setOf` `ExecutableElement`s? How can I do this?

I've also checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296204/how-to-use-funspec-overriding-in-kotlinpoet), but no so much luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to obtain a `TypeElement` using the `package` and `class` name (you will need a `ProcessingEnvironment` instance for that).

```
fun getTypeElement(
        processingEnvironment: ProcessingEnvironment,
        packageName: String,
        className: String
): TypeElement {
    return processingEnvironment.elementUtils.getTypeElement("$packageName.$className")
}
```

Then you can simply access the `enclosedElements` in the `TypeElement`:

```
val typeElement = getTypeElement(processingEnv, packageName, className)

FunSpec.overriding(getOnlyElement(methodsIn(typeElement.enclosedElements)))
```

Comment: just a small note: that when using https://github.com/Takhion/kotlin-metadata there is no need to access the processenvironment at all just `elementUtils` directly for the win. this was the thing that was confusing me actually :) thnx